# How to add Fog Lamps to Maruthi Suzuki Alto 800

Tags: electrical, suzuki, lights

I have a Suzuki Alto 800 lxi 2015 model and I would like to add Fog lamps for that, which is does not come with this model. But the Alto K10 has it. So I would like to modify it.

Can I do that ? 
and what are the pros and cons ?
Or any other easy alternation ?

Comment: First of all , Consider do you really need Fog lights, for example southern indian cities almost never need fog so the fog lights or the defogger are completely useless, i know some northern parts get foogy , still check out do you really need fog lamps.

Comment: Having no previous knowledge of these two vehicles, they both *appear* to be based off of the same chassis. I take it you'd like the fog lamps to look as though they came from the factory, and not some kluged together mess. If so, you'd have to completely remove the entire front fascia and replace it with the K10's front end (bumper, headlights, grill, hood (bonnet), fenders, and any underlying parts) in order to get it to look stock. None of these parts seem to match up between the two vehicles. Cost is going to be large: consider trading the car in on the other model.

Comment: If you feel you need them . then you will have to alter the front bumper by cutting holes in the places where there is provision, the wiring is already there for fog lamps in the LXI model since they come from a common splitter.you can cut holes, insert lamps and do the wiring which i can explain as an answer.

Comment: I agree with Paulster.. you can replace the bumper but it will look odd if not done correctly and is not a wise option which your purse will not appreciate at all

Comment: @Paulster2 wierdly wiring is easy for the fog lights but cutting holes in the bumper and inserting the lamps is whats going to be a task

Comment: @Anarach - Pretty much what I was getting at. I left this as a comment because I don't know the vehicle. Getting the fog lamps in is not an issue. *Getting them to look right* when you do is.

Comment: Lol Hope after the mod it doesnt end up looking like a Pontiac Aztec

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the differences between the car you have and the K10 with front fog lights, it appears that you would need to change the front bumper to accommodate the K10 standard fit fog lights.  If you can locate a car in the scrap yard which has the lights and bumper in the correct colour then this is probably the only economical way to do the conversion.  Otherwise you will need to order a new bumper and have it repainted in the correct colour for your vehicle.

Alongside physically fitting the lights to the front of the car you will need to connect them.  This may mean changing your dashboard switch to one from a K10 or adding an aftermarket switch plus adding the wiring loom, fuse and associated relays.

Always bear in mind with this kind of work you are modifying the vehicle which may have implications for insurance.

Alternatives would include buying and fitting in inexpensive after market front fog light kit from a manufacturer such as Ring or Hella or even trading in your vehicle against one which comes equipped with fog lights.

Comment: Wiring will definitely void warranty.

Comment: If you look at both vehicles, it will take more than a bumper change. The bumper from the K10 will not align with the headlights, grill, or fenders from the 800. Then, if you change that out to make it look right, the hood will not match the new grill. Looks as though from there back, everything has the same fitment.

Comment: In short, unless you find a K10 that's had, perhaps a rear-end impact, is the right colour and you can get everything you need from it cheaply, it will be a very expensive job.  I guess an alternative would be to get a K10 bumper and plastic-weld the foglight apertures into your existing bumper than re-paint but you'll need some skill to execute this effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest do not mess with it. Your model may have a smaller capacity alternator and this would upset the whole elctrical system and cause car break down. The foglight can add another 15% load to the system and during occasions the battery is undercharged, it may cause havoc.

Comment: Might i know how are you arriving at the 15% figure? do you have any backing for it.

Comment: Let's say each fog light bulb is 55W, a pair would be 110W. At 12v, this would draw 110/12=9A. The alternator for a tiny car like this would have an alternator of 60A or so. 9/60=15% capacity.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you can add fog lamps on a car (lower model) where there is provision to add but the manufacturer does not include it in the car.

In that case you can cut out parts of the bumper carefully, insert the exact OEM lamps which should fit perfectly and probably hook them up with your headlights so as to avoid installation of switch on the dashboard.

Or simply your can install a new bumper or a higher version of the same vehicle so you dont even have to do the dirty work.

In your case the Alto 800 does not have provision for fog lamps and that's by design to reduce cost of manufacture and acquiring by the customer.

[image]

As you can see on the Alto 800 you dont even have space to add them , manually cutting up  holes or replacing the front grill/lights will cost too much and will probably ruin the car.

**However there is an Alternative**

If you fancy a fog light you can install an aftermarket LED strip on the bumper which will give you better visibility and cool looks , they can work as a DRL also with proper wiring.

Look at the below car which is the Alto's Older sibling and does not have proper holes for fog lamps.

[image]

I feel by far this is the Cheapest option you can pursue if you need fog lamps.

You can buy cheap ones on eBAY for around 200 to 500

[LED Strips](http://www.ebay.in/sch/i.html?_odkw=led%20lights&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=led%20strips&_sacat=0)

Comment: Downvote for "hook them up with your headlights so as to avoid installation of switch on the dashboard." - that would imply that the fog lights would be on all the time the headlights were on, which dazzles other drivers, looks ridiculous, and is illegal in many places.

Comment: @NickC Well its not illegal where me and the OP  live plus i think they would be like the DRLs from Audi and BMW , i dont think they will be blinding to the oncoming traffic, i have seen them personally , Nothing annoys me more than an idiot with High beam onto the face.

Comment: i agree with @NickC hooking fog lamp with headlight is bad idea, and those cheap chinese LED strips has terrible glare and are irritating to look at during nighttime